# How to change these two functional components(TableData.js and TableSearch.js) to class components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I need to make the functional components (TableSearch.js and TableData.js ) to class components, first class component should be called **TableSearch** and second **TableData**. I just started to study the React and Redux, so it's still hard for me, also the complexity is that in these functions the object is passed by an argument (destructuring).

TableSearch.js:

```
import React from "react";
export default ({ value, onChange, onSearch }) => {
  return (
    <div className="tableSearch">
        <input type="text" className="searchInput" onChange={onChange} value={value} placeholder="Search by flight"/>
        <button className="buttonSearch" onClick={() => onSearch(value)}>Search</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

TableData.js:

```
import React from "react";
export default ({ data }) => (
     <div className="tableContainer">
  <table className="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Terminal</th>
        <th>Gate</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Destination</th>
        <th>Airline</th>
        <th>Flight</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {data.map(item => {
         const dt = new Date(item.actual);
         const mins = dt.getMinutes();
        return (
          <tr key={item.ID}>
            <td>{item.term}</td>
            <td>{item.gateNo}</td>
            <td>{`${dt.getHours()}:${mins < 10 ? '0' : ''}${mins}`}</td>
            <td>
              {item["airportToID.city_en"]
                ? item["airportToID.city_en"]
                : item["airportFromID.city_en"]}
            </td>
            <td>{item.airline.en.name}</td>
            <td>{item["planeTypeID.code"]}</td>
            <td>{item.status}</td>
          </tr>
        );
      })}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
);
```

How to change these two functional components(TableData.js and TableSearch.js) to class components?
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I will also write the main component App.js(for more information)

```
import React from "react";
import { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchData } from "../actions";
import { filter } from "../actions";
import { setSearch } from "../actions";
import TableData from "../components/TableData";
import TableSearch from "../components/TableSearch";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";
import "../components/app.css";

export function searchFilter(search, data) {
  return data.filter(n => n["planeTypeID.code"].toLowerCase().includes(search));
}

const days = ["12-11-2019", "13-11-2019", "14-11-2019"];

class Root extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onFetchData(days[this.props.propsReducer.day]);
  }

  render() {
    const { onFilter, onSetSearch, onFetchData } = this.props;
    const { search, shift, data, filteredData } = this.props.propsReducer;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="content">

        <Header/>
        <br/>
        <div className="searchTitle">SEARCH FLIGHT</div>
             <br/>
        <TableSearch value={search} onChange={e => onSetSearch(e.target.value)} 
         onSearch={value => onFilter({ search: value })}/>
             <br/>
             <br/>
        <div className="buttonShift">
          {data && Object.keys(data).map(n => (
            <button data-shift={n} onClick={e => onFilter({ shift: e.target.dataset.shift })} className={n === shift ? "active" : "noActive"}>
                {n}
            </button>
          ))}
        </div>

        <div className="row">
        <span className="title">Yesterday: </span><span className="title">Today: </span><span className="title">Tomorrow: </span>
        </div>

        <div className="buttonDays">
          {days && days.map((day, i) => (
            <button  key={day} onClick={() => onFetchData(day)} className="buttonDaysOne">
                {day} 
            </button>
          ))}
        </div>

        {data && <TableData data={filteredData} />}
          </div>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => state;

const matchDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onFilter: args => dispatch(filter(args)),
    onSetSearch: search => dispatch(setSearch(search)),
    onFetchData: day => dispatch(fetchData(day))
});

export const ConnectedRoot = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  matchDispatchToProps
)(Root);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you want to do it hope you have a good reason
but this how you should do it

TableSearch.jsx

```
import React from "react";
export default class TableSearch extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const { value, onChange, onSearch } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="tableSearch">
                <input type="text" className="searchInput" onChange={onChange} value={value} placeholder="Search by flight" />
                <button className="buttonSearch" onClick={() => onSearch(value)}>Search</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

TableData.jsx

```
import React from "react";
export default class TableData extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const { data } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="tableContainer">
                <table className="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Terminal</th>
                            <th>Gate</th>
                            <th>Time</th>
                            <th>Destination</th>
                            <th>Airline</th>
                            <th>Flight</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {data.map(item => {
                            const dt = new Date(item.actual);
                            const mins = dt.getMinutes();
                            return (
                                <tr key={item.ID}>
                                    <td>{item.term}</td>
                                    <td>{item.gateNo}</td>
                                    <td>{`${dt.getHours()}:${mins < 10 ? '0' : ''}${mins}`}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        {item["airportToID.city_en"]
                                            ? item["airportToID.city_en"]
                                            : item["airportFromID.city_en"]}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{item.airline.en.name}</td>
                                    <td>{item["planeTypeID.code"]}</td>
                                    <td>{item.status}</td>
                                </tr>
                            );
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```